# Unable to create a windows salve node for jenkins

Tags: jenkins, master-slave

I have setup a master on Ubuntu machine and want to create a salve on Windows 10. While launching the agent I am facing following issue. Can someone please help.

```
just before slave javed_pc gets launched ...
executing pre-launch scripts ...
[2017-04-21 10:26:54] [windows-slaves] Connecting to 172.26.152.23
Checking if Java exists
java -version returned 1.8.0.
[2017-04-21 10:26:56] [windows-slaves] Copying jenkins-slave.xml
[2017-04-21 10:26:56] [windows-slaves] Copying slave.jar
[2017-04-21 10:26:56] [windows-slaves] Starting the service
ERROR: Unexpected error in launching an agent. This is probably a bug in Jenkins
org.jinterop.dcom.common.JIException: Service Logon Failure
    at org.jvnet.hudson.wmi.Win32Service$Implementation.start(Win32Service.java:149)
Caused: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor206.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.kohsuke.jinterop.JInteropInvocationHandler.invoke(JInteropInvocationHandler.java:140)
Caused: java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy64.start(Unknown Source)
    at hudson.os.windows.ManagedWindowsServiceLauncher.launch(ManagedWindowsServiceLauncher.java:342)
    at hudson.slaves.SlaveComputer$1.call(SlaveComputer.java:262)
    at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$2.call(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:46)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the [JENKINS Windows Slaves Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Windows+Slaves+Plugin), check if one of the reason listed in "[Windows slaves fail to start via DCOM](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Windows+slaves+fail+to+start+via+DCOM)" would apply in your case.
It lists a wide variety of reasons, from the Windows account used, to network, registry, security reasons.

Make sure you don't have a proxy issue, where Jenkins would try and use said proxy to access a machine (Windows here) on your LAN: the environment variable `no_proxy` should be used to exclude your local domain.

The [OP Javed Ahmed](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5961361/javed-ahmed) reports having solve it with:

> In '`Configure Global security`' settings, when you check '`Enable Security`' option, then it allows you to connect via java web start.
>   Otherwise It was not showing the the option to connect through java web start and connecting via windows service is a pain.

Comment: Thank you Vonc, Actually I have solved it. In 'Configure Global security' settings when you check 'Enable Security' option then it allows you to connect via java web start. Otherwise It was not showing the the option to connect through java web start and connecting via windows service is a pain.

Comment: @JavedAhmed Great! I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.